# Setting Turn server on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, webrtc, stun, turn, screensharing

I am using EC2(Amazon Linux 2). I created Turn server

```
0: log file opened: /var/log/turn_8708_2020-07-08.log
0: 
RFC 3489/5389/5766/5780/6062/6156 STUN/TURN Server
Version Coturn-4.5.0.3 'dan Eider'
0: 
Max number of open files/sockets allowed for this process: 300000
0: 
Due to the open files/sockets limitation,
max supported number of TURN Sessions possible is: 150000 (approximately)
0: 

==== Show him the instruments, Practical Frost: ====

0: TLS supported
0: DTLS supported
0: DTLS 1.2 supported
0: TURN/STUN ALPN supported
0: Third-party authorization (oAuth) supported
0: GCM (AEAD) supported
0: OpenSSL compile-time version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
0: 
0: SQLite is not supported
0: Redis is not supported
0: PostgreSQL is not supported
0: MySQL is not supported
0: MongoDB is not supported
0: 
0: Default Net Engine version: 3 (UDP thread per CPU core)

=====================================================

0: Config file found: /usr/local/etc/turnserver.conf
0: log file opened: /var/log/turnserver_2020-07-08.log
0: Config file found: /usr/local/etc/turnserver.conf
0: Domain name: 
0: Default realm: meetmocha.com
0: 
CONFIGURATION ALERT: you specified long-term user accounts, (-u option) 
    but you did not specify the long-term credentials option
    (-a or --lt-cred-mech option).
    I am turning --lt-cred-mech ON for you, but double-check your configuration.
0: WARNING: cannot find certificate file: turn_server_cert.pem (1)
0: WARNING: cannot start TLS and DTLS listeners because certificate file is not set properly
0: WARNING: cannot find private key file: turn_server_pkey.pem (1)
0: WARNING: cannot start TLS and DTLS listeners because private key file is not set properly
0: NO EXPLICIT LISTENER ADDRESS(ES) ARE CONFIGURED
0: ===========Discovering listener addresses: =========
0: Listener address to use: 127.0.0.1
0: Listener address to use: 172.26.193.9
0: Listener address to use: ::1
0: =====================================================
0: Total: 1 'real' addresses discovered
0: =====================================================
0: NO EXPLICIT RELAY ADDRESS(ES) ARE CONFIGURED
0: ===========Discovering relay addresses: =============
0: Relay address to use: 172.26.193.9
0: Relay address to use: ::1
0: =====================================================
0: Total: 2 relay addresses discovered
0: =====================================================
0: pid file created: /var/run/turnserver.pid
0: IO method (main listener thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: WARNING: I cannot support STUN CHANGE_REQUEST functionality because only one IP address is provided
0: Wait for relay ports initialization...
0:   relay 172.26.193.9 initialization...
0:   relay 172.26.193.9 initialization done
0:   relay ::1 initialization...
0:   relay ::1 initialization done
0: Relay ports initialization done
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: turn server id=1 created
0: IPv4. SCTP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 172.26.193.9:3478
0: IPv6. SCTP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv6. TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: turn server id=0 created
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 172.26.193.9:3478
0: IPv6. TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv4. UDP listener opened on: 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. UDP listener opened on: 172.26.193.9:3478
0: IPv6. UDP listener opened on: ::1:3478
0: Total General servers: 2
0: IO method (admin thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv4. CLI listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5766
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
```

I have tested My turn server on Trickle ICE page:

[image]
But When I am calling Turn server from my Javascript code still not able to make screen sharing connection on different network while if I make connection on same network than successfully made.

For example, I share my laptop screen to my mobile both device connected with same wifi than work perfectly but if internet connection different than not working so I set up Turn server on my EC2 server. After adding Turn server to my Javascript code I am not able to share screen on different network.

Please can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: You are required to specify a username and credential, when setting up your TURN server on EC2. Then, from JavaScript, you're supposed to use the username and password that you set up for your TURN server.

Comment: Take a look at this article. https://meetrix.io/blog/webrtc/coturn/installation.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this way. Now I am getting 228: session 000000000000000002: user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised in my Turn server. {
    urls: 'turn:<EC2 public IP>:3478',
    username: 'adcatHdfc',
    credential: '123456'
} I am adding this code in my javascript. Please can you help me why this unauthoried error is coming now